# Cannot initialize "git svn" on a folder because of a Perl conflict

Tags: git, perl, svn

My machine is on Windows. I am trying to migrate a SVN repository to Bitbucket. The first step is to use "git svn init" on the svn URL. However, when I do any `git svn` command, I get this Perl conflict:

```
  C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn: Perl lib version (5.26.2) doesn't match executable 'perl' version (5.26.1) at /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/Config.pm line 62.
    Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/lib.pm line 6.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/lib.pm line 6.
    Compilation failed in require at C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 37.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 37.
```

How do I sync these perl versions up?

I believe I have the right environment path: *C:\Perl64\site\bin*, but I can't figure out how to match the two perl versions so I can run any `git svn` commands.

Comment: I'd guess that the normal-Perl installation messes up with the perl provided by your mighw64 git-installation. So renaming the Windows-perl-installation (e.g from C:\Perl64 C:\Perl64_2) during your migration might help.

Comment: I think that was the Active State installation. I'm not sure where the Windows installation is

Comment: Yes, sure - i meant the native installation. You currently are obviously mixing 2 perls, so simply disable the native (ActiveState/Strawberry/whatever) during your migration process.